# protobuf: consecutive serialize and deserialize to/from socket

Tags: c#, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

My simple communication between C++ client and C# server got stuck after a message was serialized to socket (SerializeToFileDescritor).

C++ client:

```
  Person person;
  person.set_id(54321);
  person.set_name("bla");
  person.mutable_address()->set_line1("sdfa");
  person.mutable_address()->set_line2("asdfsdfa");

  cout << person.id() << endl << person.name() << endl;
  cout << person.address().line2() << endl;

  person.SerializeToFileDescriptor(s);

  ZeroCopyInputStream* raw_input = new FileInputStream(s);
  CodedInputStream* coded_input = new CodedInputStream(raw_input);

  Person person2;

  person2.ParseFromFileDescriptor(s);

  cout << person2.id() << endl << person2.name() << endl;
  cout << person2.address().line2() << endl;
```

C# server

```
var sockServer = new TcpListener(2048);
sockServer.Start();

var person = new Person { Id = 123456, Name = "Fred", Address = new Address { Line1 = "Flat 1", Line2 = "The Meadows ar garą " } };

var socket = sockServer.AcceptSocket();
Stream str = new NetworkStream(socket);

var response = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(str);
Console.WriteLine(response.Id);

Serializer.Serialize(str, person);
```

It seems to me ridiculously stupid it doesn't work.

If I remove any one of these: person.SerializeToFileDescriptor(s) or person2.ParseFromFileDescriptor(s), the other will work.

What should I do to make them work both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour *for a root object* is to consume all data to the end of the stream. And since you don't close the stream, that end never comes.

If your intention is to send multiple objects down the same socket (which is pretty normal) then you need to give it a clue. The most common approach would be to prefix each message with the length of the data about to be sent. This could be in a fixed-32 int, or in a varint if convenient. You can then read that at the consumer.

How you then handle that depends on the caller; protobuf-net has a `DeserializeWithLengthPrefix` that will handle various forms of encoding, with-or-without an additional field marker (in the case of varint, to make it a valid protobuf stream). For example:

```
Person person = Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<Person>(str,
        PrefixStyle.Fixed32, 0);
```

Comment: I changed Deserialize to DeserializeWithLengthPrefix in C# server but How should I adjust C++ client? I tried mimic the prefix adding uint32 like that: person.ByteSize() 0 0 0 . No success.

Comment: @lord - I'm not a C++ guru, I'm afraid - but I would *expect* it to make it easy to get at the length of the data pretty easily. If that is what `person.ByteSize()` is, then great! I'd need to know exactly what ends up on the wire - i.e. does `ByteSize()` result in one byte? or 4? (i.e. do we need the zeros)

Answer (score 2):

If you intend to send multiple messages, [this](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/techniques.html#streaming) might be useful.